# Please help...is my implementation for counting prime numbers in Java doing what it should do?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've been given a description of how I am to implement a prime number generator using Java; but I'm not sure if I am doing it properly. I was hoping someone could give me some general advice for how to improve my implementation! Please don't give me an answer as this is homework and I'd like to crack this myself/become a better programmer/not cheat !

I will post the description and my solution below, basically I would just like to know some general things - have I followed the instructions properly (most important as I find the language used a little confusing) and if I could make my program any better (if so some general tips would be nice so I can figure out how...I think my use of the logarithm is way off, but I can't figure out a better way to use it)!

Apologies if this isn't allowed - if it isn't then please ignore or delete ! Thank you very much for your help! :)

Description :

> Prime( int initialCapacity ): The class
>   constructor. The purpose of the
>   constructor is to compute and store
>   the first initialCapacity prime �first initialCapacity primefirst initialCapacity primefirst i
>   numbers. The idea is that you compute
>   the numbers once and store them so
>   that you can re-use them several
>   times. You should use an ArrayList to
>   store the prime numbers. An algorithm
>   for computing prime numbers is
>   provided in the next section.
>
> 1. Start with an empty list of prime numbers. You may represent this list
>      using an ArrayList.
> 2. While the size of the ArrayList is not equal to n, consider the next
>      candidate prime number. Initially, the
>      next candidate prime number should be
>      2, but otherwise it should be the
>      successor of the previous candidate
>      prime number.
> 3. If the candidate prime number is a prime then add it to the list.
> 4. Continue with Step 2.
>
> Note that this algorithm suggests that you
>   should use a while loop. Step 3 of the
>   previous algorithm requires that you
>   know how to decide whether a given
>   candidate prime, c > 1, is a prime
>   number. As a matter of fact, the
>   denition of prime numbers already
>   suggests a naive algorithm. For
>   example, you could use a while loop to
>   check that c %i 6= 0 for all positive
>   integers i such that 1 < i and i < c.
>   However, it is not dicult to see that
>   a much better method is making sure
>   that c % p 6= 0 for all prime numbers
>   p such that p < c. Using the primes in
>   your ArrayList this is easy as pie.is
>   method is the method which you are
>   supposed to use. Note again that this
>   suggest that you use a while loop.
>   Finally, your implementation should be
>   ecient and should not waste checks of
>   the form c % p 6= 0 or c % p = 0. So,
>   you should stop cheking as soon as c %
>   p = 0 for some of the primes in
>   ArrayList.

My solution is as follows :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Prime {

  public static void main( String[] args ){

  }
  public static void prime( int initialCapacity){
    int index=2;
    int logOfInitialCapacity = initialCapacity / (int)(Math.log(initialCapacity));
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfPrimeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(logOfInitialCapacity);
    boolean[] isPrimeNumber = new boolean[initialCapacity + 1]; // boolean defaults to
    // false

    for (int i=0;i==initialCapacity;i++) {
        isPrimeNumber[index] = true;
      }
      while ( index <= listOfPrimeNumbers.size() )
      {
        if (isPrimeNumber[index]) {
          listOfPrimeNumbers.add(index);
        }
      for (int j = index; j * index <= initialCapacity; j++) {
          isPrimeNumber[index * j] = false;
      }
         // Now mark the multiple of i as non-prime number
        index++;
      }
  }

}
```

which should compute the first initialCapacity of prime numbers and save them in an arrayList as the question asks...I'm just not sure if I have done exactly as the question says. It's probably more a product of studying all day and being a little worn out than anything else !

Thanks a lot for the help and for reading all of this; sorry for the long post.

Comment: Do you have a particular question in mind here?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Is it implemented following the specifications of the question, and also is my logarithm on initialCapacity correct/performing any function on the ArrayList ?

Comment: "The class constructor" seems to contradict `public static void prime`. Did you simplify your code to show the bit in question, or have you not actually defined a Prime class?

Comment: You may want to write a program that uses your function and test for a small number of primes, as you should easily know the first 10 or so prime numbers.  It isn't implemented correctly, and by testing it you will see which part isn't correct, as you will split your function into multiple smaller functions so you can test each part individually, which will make you into a better programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution doesn't really match the problem description.

The problem description prescribes primality testing (i.e. given a candidate prime, test whether it is prime). It also wants `initialCapacity` primes.

The problems with your solution:

1. it seems to be trying to perform sieving
2. it is inefficient, because the multiples of a composite number are crossed out.
3. it finds the primes up to `initialCapacity` (not the first `initialCapacity` primes - to see the difference, try `initialCapacity = 1`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Can I ask what is wrong with me trying to perform sieving though ? Is that not what I should be doing ?! Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: It feels like you're meant to perform trial division, from the question, instead of sieving (from the "Note" part). Also, since you're trying to find `n` primes, the ideal capacity of `isPrimeNumber` is not certain (although you can solve `k/logk = n` and budget some buffer).

Answer (score 2):

You can answer your own question with this:

http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt

If these aren't in your list, your code isn't doing it correctly.

You'll want to read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes